# Are @property(nonatomic)ivar @property(nonatomic,assign)ivar the same or different?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, xcode

Are `@property(nonatomic)ivar` and `@property(nonatomic,assign)ivar` the same or different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1):

> assign - 
>   Specifies that the setter uses simple assignment. **This attribute is the default.**

So no, as far as I know they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Objective-C 101 (retain vs assign) NSString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380338/objective-c-101-retain-vs-assign-nsstring)